# Pandas np.array column in AWS DLAMI

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2

I'm running into problems inserting np.arrays into a pandas dataframe column.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3])
x['a'] = x.apply( lambda x : np.zeros(30) ,axis=1)
```

When running this on my local machine, I have no problems and get the proper output

```
In [6]: x.head()
Out[6]: 
   0                                                  a
0  0  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1  1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2  2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3  3  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

But when running this on a Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 20.0 (ami-0f9e8c4a1305ecd22)

I get the error message

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 30), indices imply (4, 1)
```

Both machines are running Python 3.6.5.  For now my workaround is to stick the arrays in a list.

```
x['a'] = x.apply( lambda x : [np.zeros(30)] ,axis=1)
```

Why is my code working locally but failing on the AMI instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for opening this issue.

I was able replicate this issue on a v21.2 ubuntu DLAMI instance. We are using pandas version `0.22.0` on DLAMI.

Locally on my machine I am using version pandas `0.24.2` and don't face the issue above.

Thanks for reporting this, we will take action and fix the problem shortly.

On your end, for now I would recommend to uninstall pandas and reinstall pandas as follows:

`pip uninstall pandas`
`pip install pandas==0.24.2`